# How to sample clustering to estimate precision and recall?

Tags: clustering, sampling, precision-recall

There is a system containing $N$ clusters and in each cluster there are some elements. The clusters' sizes varies dramatically and most of the clusters are singletons.

I need to know the precision and recall of this system, but since I need to check it manually it is impossible to check too many units.

My question is: if I draw samples, the sampling unit should be cluster or element?

Also, precision is a kind of easy to check (given I know the definition of each cluster), but how could I check the recall? I need to check in the scope of sample only, or I need to search from the entire population?
Is there anything else I need to know?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you have to check manually? Plus P&R make direct sense only in case of binary classification, how do you want to generalize into many clusters?

Comment: @user6397: Please clarify what kind of clusters you have. Are you talking about classifier validation with clustered (hierarchical) structure of the samples or are you talking about validation of cluster analysis results?

Answer (score 1):

For cluster algorithm evaluation you have to create small manual clusters and check how well they distributed among resulted clusters. Check this article http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/evaluation-of-clustering-1.html

Answer (score 1):

### Drawing Validation Samples with Clustered Data Structure

You need to draw samples from a structural level where samples are statistically independent.

So if I have several patients (= your clusters?) and varying numbers of (e.g. repeated) measurements per patient (= your elements?) then I draw test *patients*. That is, unless I can show that the variance between patients is negligible compared to the variance between measurements of one patient.

### Validation of Cluster Analysis

I'd use someting like cluster purity and/or the number of clusters samples of a given group are assigned to.
Precision, Recall & Co. don't seem quite appropriate: Think of a very bad *classifier* that always assigns B to class A samples and vice versa. That would be 0 precision and recall. But cluster analysis doesn't claim that the cluster where it assigns all B samples is actually class B. You'd need to assume something like the cluster with highest B predictions is actually B. So you'd always get at least $\frac{1}{n_{classes}}$ correct assignments due to this assumption.

### Generalization of Precision & Recall

I use the following generalizations. I derived them from the medical diagnostics meaning, where the binary case disease X vs. not disease X (often called healthy in every day language)

(see p. 12 of http://softclassval.r-forge.r-project.org/Beleites2011b.pdf for an illustration)

- recall = sensitivity = How good does the classifier recognize class C samples? = fraction of cases where reference says it is class C that is (correctly) assigned to class C,
- specificity = How good does the classifer recognize that a sample does not come from class C? = fraction of cases where reference says it is not class C that is (correctly) not assigned to class C.
- precision = positive predictive value = If the classifier says it is C, what is the probability that this is correct? = fraction of cases with reference C of predicted class C cases.
- negative predictive value = Given the classifier said it is not class C, what is the probability this is correct? = fraction of cases with reference not C of cases predicted to be something else than C.